# PHP Calendar displaying list of events

Tags: php

I have a database table that has two columns `eventName|eventDate`. I have created a function that takes in a startDate and endDate, I want to display the list of events in a ListView with each date as the header.

In my brief example below, I know I can retrieve the full event listings with SQL. How do I then slot the event headers in so that I can return them in a properly formatted array?

```
function retrieveEvents($startDate, $endDate) {
    // run SQL query
    // 
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // how do I write this part such that I can output event headers in my array        
            $events = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

So my intended output is

```
1st July 2013 ($startDate)
- Tea with President - 1300h
- Mow the lawn - 1330h
- Shave the cat - 1440h
2nd July 2013
- Shave my head - 0800h
3rd July 2013
4th July 2013 ($endDate)
- Polish the car - 1000h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing my checking in PHP and print a new row only when a different date is detected.

Codes below in case it serves someone's needs in future.

```
<?php
        $currentPrintDay = 0;
        $currentPrintMonth = 0;
        $currentPrintYear = 0;

        echo "<table>"
        foreach($reservationsToShow as $row):
        // get day, month, year of this entry
        $timestamp = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
        $day = date('d', $timestamp);
        $month = date('m', $timestamp);
        $year = date('Y', $timestamp);

        // if it does not match the current printing date, assign it to the current printing date,
        // assign it, print a new row as the header before continuing
        if($day != $currentPrintDay || $month != $currentPrintMonth || $year != $currentPrintYear) {
            $currentPrintDay = $day;
            $currentPrintMonth = $month;
            $currentPrintYear = $year;

            echo 
            "<tr>" .
            "<td colspan='100%'>". date('d-m-Y', $timestamp) . "</td>" .
            "</tr>";
        }
        // continue to print event details from here on...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTableName` WHERE `eventDate` >= $startDate AND `eventDate` <= $endDate
```

PS: I'm not sure about the quotes arount the variables in your query.

PPS: never use * to select your columns, always only select the columns you need. Here I'm using it because I don't know the names of your columns

Comment: hi Daniel. thanks for the response. I know how to write the query. but I dont know how to properly format the output array so that I can have the date as respective headers. :)

Comment: I think it'd be more efficient to select the data you need in your SQL query, instead of getting all results from your database, and proccess them in PHP

Comment: yeah I am already using the query you have suggested above. more fundamentally, my problem lies with how to display my desired output above, because I want to show the date first before I list the events.

Comment: Then you should only `SELECT \`eventDate\`` and output it by doing:

`$event = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query(SELECT * FROM \`yourTableName\` WHERE \`eventDate\` >= $startDate AND \`eventDate\` <= $endDate));
echo $event->eventDate;
`